# findOneAndUpdate for updating DB in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

my data is like this

```
{
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5ec05df7755a8f0c4c7945bd"),
                        "name" : "play",
                        "__v" : 0
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5ec05df7755a8f0c4c7945be"),
                        "name" : "eat",
                        "__v" : 0
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5ec05df7755a8f0c4c7945bf"),
                        "name" : "study",
                        "__v" : 0
                }

        ],
        "name" : "go",
        "__v" : 2
}
```

i want to remove a specific element from the array with id. i have my update like this, but still my data is not getting updated. i have seen other posts and tried different versions of update but nothing helped.

```
list.findOneAndUpdate({name:ln},{$pull : {items:{_id:req.body.id}}},{useFindAndModify:false},
      function(err,result){
      if(!err){
        result.save()
        res.redirect("/"+listname)
      }
    }
```

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to perform this action, mongo DB need to find the correct `_id` which you need to remove from the object. So instead of parsing just `String` value as `_id`, you just need to convert it to `ObjectId`.

You can use the following command in order to convert the `String` value to `ObjectId`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

list.findOneAndUpdate({name:ln},{$pull : {items:{_id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.id)}}},{useFindAndModify:false},
      function(err,result){
      if(!err){
        result.save()
        res.redirect("/"+listname)
      }
    }
```

Here is the query that I have Tried out.

```
 db.getCollection('list').findOneAndUpdate({name:'go'},{$pull : {items:{_id:ObjectId('5ec05df7755a8f0c4c7945bd')}}},{useFindAndModify:false})
```

Here is the result which I am getting after run the above query.

[image]